# UITableView scrollViewDidScroll fired on animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7, uiscrollview

So most of the problems people have with this particular event is to have `scrollViewDidScroll` fire when there is animation happening. My case is just the opposite. I feel that `scrollViewDidScroll` should NOT be firing in my case.

Let me further explain.

I am animating things in scrollViewDidScroll and this was working perfectly until I moved UITableView into a UIView class.

```
- (void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
   // Animation code here.
   NSLog(@"scrollViewDidScroll");
}

- (void) scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
   NSLog(@"scrollViewDidEndDecelerating");
   NSArray *indexPaths = [_myTableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];
   [_myTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[indexPaths objectAtIndex:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
}
```

What this provides is a smooth scrolling experience that snaps back to a previous table row. The console can verify that `scrollViewDidScroll` event is firing because of `scrollToRowAtIndexPath`.

Console:

```
2014-03-31 22:21:43.346 Project[45843:a0b] scrollViewDidScroll
2014-03-31 22:21:43.379 Project[45843:a0b] scrollViewDidScroll
2014-03-31 22:21:43.429 Project[45843:a0b] scrollViewDidScroll
2014-03-31 22:21:43.462 Project[45843:a0b] scrollViewDidScroll
2014-03-31 22:21:43.479 Project[45843:a0b] scrollViewDidEndDecelerating
2014-03-31 22:21:43.496 Project[45843:a0b] scrollViewDidScroll
2014-03-31 22:21:43.513 Project[45843:a0b] scrollViewDidScroll
2014-03-31 22:21:43.529 Project[45843:a0b] scrollViewDidScroll
```

Onto the questions:

**1. How can I ensure that the event `scrollViewDidScroll` only fires due to user interaction and not automation from code?** 
**2. Is there another method that provides the same functionality as `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` without triggering `scrollViewDidScroll`?**

Comment: As per my knowledge, you can't scroll without delegate method gets called. One thing you can do is by scrolling programmatically you can set a flag and use it in delegate method. If you are scrolling programmatically reset the flag. I hope this will help you..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I know this is a very old question. I just have been in a similar situation that I need to run some code only when the user is scrolling but not when I call `scrollToRowAtIndexPath`. I have found an easier solution for this using the scrollView variables `dragging` and `decelerating`.

we have 3 cases of scrolling here.

1. user is dragging
2. user just ended dragging and the tableview is decelrating
3. programmatically called `scrollForRowAtIndexPath:`

All of the cases above will trigger `scrollViewDidScroll:` **but**

1. user is dragging `dragging` is **True** and `decelerating` is **False**
2. user just ended dragging and the tableview is decelrating `dragging` is **False** and `decelerating` is **True**
3. programmatically called `scrollForRowAtIndexPath:` `dragging` is **False** and `decelerating` is **False**

So your code will be like something like this:

```
- (void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (scrollView.dragging)
     {
       // Do what you want when user is dragging
     } else if (scrollView.decelerating) 
     {
       // Do what you want when table is decelerating after finished dragging
     } else 
     {
       // Do what you want when table is scrolling programmatically.
     }
}
```

Or if you want to just distinguish the scrolling progammatically

```
- (void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (scrollView.dragging || scrollView.decelerating)
     {
       // Scrolling by the user
     } else 
     {
       // Scrolling by the code
     }
}
```

Comment: This is a much more elegant solution than rolling my own! Changing this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Soon after I posted the question, I took a small break, came back to the problem and figured it out. Should of done that sooner instead of wasting a few hours. bleh!

The solution is simple, set a `bool` flag that gets set before any progammatic scrolling and then change that after the animation is done using the event `scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation`.

```
bool performingAutomatedScroll = false;

- (void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

  // If we are scrolling because of code, don't use any animations.
  if (performingAutomatedScroll) return;

  // Animation code here.
}

- (void) scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

  performingAutomatedScroll = true;
  NSArray *indexPaths = [_myTableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];
  [_myTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[indexPaths objectAtIndex:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
  [_myTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[_timeCarousel indexPathsForVisibleRows] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

}

- (void) scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate {

  if (!decelerate) {
    performingAutomatedScroll = true;
    NSArray *indexPaths = [_myTableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];
    [_myTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[indexPaths objectAtIndex:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
    [_myTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[_timeCarousel indexPathsForVisibleRows] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
  }

}

-(void)scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
  performingAutomatedScroll = false;
}
```